# PHP error on Function.php

Tags: php-errors

A client asked for some assistance in connecting up some Snippet Sync files and after uploading the files and Submitting the settings I get the following error when I try to load the home page:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(683) : eval()'d code on line 712

The site is running EE 2.5.5 and I can access the control panel without difficulty.

I would appreciate any assistance available on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you updated the functions.php file? Seems to be corrupted!

Comment: I have not done anything with the functions.php file. Since this is a 2.5.5 site, what would be the best option?

Comment: Solved your issue already? I have really no idea what to do. Debugging the functions.php file? What files did you update?

Comment: The problem wan't with the functions.php file, it was bad code in one of the snippets where a value was not found and was causing the extra }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an `eval()` error, which means the syntax in your templates is incorrect.

Check the snippets you recently changed, and in particular look for something like:

```
{if something == "nothing"}

{/if}} <-- oops! extra closing bracket
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, I haven't been able to spot any extra closing brackets, but it lead me to a search of all the snippets. There appears to be some erroneous coding coding on with gwcode_categories, which I will pursue separately. Thanks for your help.